# Time based sliding windows in Rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

i am testing Rethinkdb for a specific application

i have a collection of events each with it is own timestamp eg:

```
  [{ event: "event1" , timestamp: "2016-05-28T00:01:00Z" },
   { event: "event2" , timestamp: "2016-05-28T00:02:00Z" },
   { event: "event3" , timestamp: "2016-05-28T00:03:00Z" },
```

]

and suppose that now is "2016-05-28T00:02:00Z".

is it possible to run a sliding window ** between() and  change() query** on rethinkdb that works on time based events in order to extract events that are happening in this minute?

I know that there is the operator between() but in the documentation is written that r.now() is evaluated **only** when the query is fired and not during time.

Thank-you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to do that inside of RethinkDB.  You could subscribe to all changes on the table and post-filter on the client, which would actually work pretty well since most writes will be setting the timestamp to something within the last minute.

Comment: Thanks, that's really a shame anyway is there a library, pattern that can you recommend?

Comment: Just `table.changes` and then loop over the results and reject the ones you don't want would be my advice.